# How could I simulate an offline directory with Heroku?

Tags: php, perl, heroku

I used to have an offline directory on my server with Perl scripts to dynamically create files.

Say this directory was in an offline directory for security reasons (`/server/back/scripts`) I used to access it with exec(`/server/back/scripts/auto.pl $arguments`)

Contents of auto.pl:

```
system('cp /server/back/includes/default /server/front/ann/'.$enc.'.php');
system('chmod 555 /server/front/ann/'.$enc.'.php');
system("perl -pi -e 's/string/".$key."/g' /server/front/ann/".$enc.".php");
```

This script copy-paste a default file with garbage values to a public directory, and replace garbage values with something else while setting up the rights we want.

**how can I reproduce this on Heroku? - if not possible is there any way to at least reproduce the behavior of this script?**

Comment: When you say "off line" do you mean that this perl is run from the command line?  Or is it run as part of the web application?  Or cron/scheduled job?  It makes a difference.

Comment: Do you mind picking one if the answers below?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the goal of this script was to inject keys/credentials into your PHP application by searching/replacing.

Heroku encourages configuration via environment variables, especially keys/credentials.

You should add your keys via the Heroku command line tool:

```
heroku config:set MY_API_KEY=super-secret-hex-goes-here
```

... and then pull in the values from the environment on your dyno in your PHP code:

```
$api_key = getenv('MY_API_KEY');
```

This will allow you to provision keys/secrets for each running application on Heroku without having to store anything in source code.

Answer (score 2):

Heroku **does not expose the File system of the current web dyno**. So you can't make any changes to the files to have an impact on the running server.

Files can be **changed if you have the file in the code base** itself. So, you could commit the change and deploy on Heroku.

If these variables, that you are talking about **have to be used system wide** then the best way is to use **Environment variables** as mentioned in Winfield's answer.

You can **set and unset Environment variables** using command :

> heroku config:set VAR_NAME=value [VAR_NAME_2=value.........]
>
> heroku config:unset VAR_NAME [VAR_NAME2.......]

If you need to **maintain a file with current values of Environment variables** , then you can use this command :

> heroku config:pull --overwrite

This will get all the **Environment variables** currently set on **server and store them in .env file**.
Then you can **update the values in .env file locally itself** and update the same on server by command:

> heroku config:push

This will **replace all current values on server with the values in the .env file**

Read more about environmet variables here : https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars

Comment: Why is this downvoted? This answer is 100% correct. You cannot directly access a Heroku dyno's filesystem and edit the files. 'heroku run' commands [run in a one-off dyno](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/one-off-dynos). The best practice is to use environment variables for your keys, and for your applications to read those environment variables, as @Winfield has said before.